# Tags that need a Wiki entry and Questions with untagged after losing their tag to a purge, how can I help?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The purge of tags without wikis on only one question has us currently sitting at 70 [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions. That is a great number of questions.

We could resolve this by making additional questions or creating a tag wiki. I don't have edit access, so my best method of helping is making additional questions.

Shall I begin asking away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, good questions are always welcome! And we have a healthy voting culture here, so if you ask one good question (or write a good answer), you'll likely have [enough reputation to create tags](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), suggest edits adding those new tags to [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions *and* suggest tag wiki excerpts for them, so that they remain tagged. (But please don't bump too many posts at once.) That is [actually how I started out here ...](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/12315/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=6)